# Heroku database error on production: PG::UndefinedTable Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I run the app on Heroku, this is what comes out of the logs:

```
2018-04-15T22:51:12.806576+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-15T22:51:12.806420 #4]  INFO -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b] Started GET "/patients" for 112.205.217.139 at 2018-04-15 22:51:12 +0000
2018-04-15T22:51:12.808307+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-15T22:51:12.808235 #4]  INFO -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b] Processing by PatientsController#index as HTML
2018-04-15T22:51:12.811835+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-15T22:51:12.811756 #4]  INFO -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]   Rendering patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-04-15T22:51:15.563600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/patients" host=jdent-patrec.herokuapp.com request_id=cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b fwd="112.205.217.139" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2757ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-04-15T22:51:15.557887+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.557726 #4] DEBUG -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]   [1m[36mPatient Load (2.7ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"[0m
2018-04-15T22:51:15.558988+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.558899 #4]  INFO -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]   Rendered patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2747.0ms)
2018-04-15T22:51:15.559386+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.559271 #4]  INFO -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2751ms (ActiveRecord: 2589.2ms)
2018-04-15T22:51:15.560650+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.560581 #4] FATAL -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]   
2018-04-15T22:51:15.560736+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.560661 #4] FATAL -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b] ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "patients" does not exist
2018-04-15T22:51:15.560739+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"
2018-04-15T22:51:15.560741+00:00 app[web.1]:                                  ^
2018-04-15T22:51:15.560742+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"):
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561063+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.560972 #4] FATAL -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     22:     </thead>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561066+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     23:   
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561067+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     24:     <tbody>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561069+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     25:       <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561071+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     26:         <tr>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561072+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     27:           <td><%= patient.id %></td>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561074+00:00 app[web.1]: [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]     28:           <td><%= patient.first_name %></td>
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561133+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.561061 #4] FATAL -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b]   
2018-04-15T22:51:15.561200+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-04-15T22:51:15.561139 #4] FATAL -- : [cd1ed367-c720-4568-ac03-a3b1bec4fc1b] app/views/patients/index.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_patients_index_html_erb___2618543925626266733_38249580'
```

Error pic:

[image]

I've been trying to look for the problem for days but to no avail.

Comment: What do you get for Patient.all from Rails console? (heroku run rails console)

Comment: is there more you can share from the error message output?

Comment: I edited the question to show the full error log when going to the patients index

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate` on the heroku box?

Comment: `heroku run rails db:migrate` (https://mentalized.net/journal/2017/04/22/run-rails-migrations-on-heroku-deploy/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently create this table?  If so, try

```
heroku run rails db:migrate
```